# I'm getting File format b'\x1aE\xdf\xa3' not understood. Only 'RIFF' and 'RIFX' supported error when I want to read a wav format audio file

Tags: python

I want to save the uploaded voice with `wav` format in FastAPI using the below code:

```
@router.post('/save')
async def save_audio(audio = Form()):
      filename = str(uuid.uuid4())
      out_file_path = f"{filename}.wav"
      with open(out_file_path, "wb") as buffer:
           shutil.copyfileobj(audio.file, buffer)
```

Everything is fine and I can play the voice with the music player, but when I want to open this file with `wavfile` package using this code:

```
rate, data = await wavfile.read(f"{filename}.wav")
```

I got the `File format b'\x1aE\xdf\xa3' not understood. Only 'RIFF' and 'RIFX' supported.`  error.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with `librosa` package

```
data, sampleRate = await librosa.load(f'{filename}.wav')
```